# How to access json value without colon?

Tags: json

I have a JSON like this

```
  getViewsManager: [Function] },
  state: {},
  url:
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: '',
     query: {},
     pathname: '/profile/nmac1',
     path: '/profile/nmac1',
     href: '/profile/nmac1' },
```

How can I access `url. hostname`

Comment: I think your json is bad.. url : contain url object

Comment: @RahulPawar so I can't read the values?

Comment: @niksmc Can you customize you json is it in your hand before access?

Comment: that is just the way that it is printed using console log I think (its showing the type, note the others with [Function] etc). This is a JSON object, not a JSON string, it doesn't need parsing.  try `jsonObj.url.hostname` (jsonObj is your variable name).

Comment: @Scriptable please add as answer as its working.

Comment: @niksmac done, glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just the way that it is printed using console log I think (its showing the type, note the others with `[Function]` etc). This is a JSON object, not a JSON string, it doesn't need parsing. try

```
jsonObj.url.hostname // (jsonObj is your variable name)
```